# Are CRF/MRF/GRF still used widely in computer vision?

Tags: references, computer-vision, conditional-random-field, markov-random-field

I've tried to find recent (the year 2020) popular works that use Markov/Gibbs/Conditional Random Fields. My approach was: go to Google Scholar and find the works, citing a few relevant works on this topic: *"Exact optimization for Markov random fields with convex priors"* by H. Ishikawa, *"An experimental comparison of min-cut/max-flow algorithms for energy minimization in vision"* by Yu. Boykov and V. Kolmogorov and *"Convergent Tree-Reweighted Message Passing for Energy Minimization"* by V. Kolmogorov.

Surprisingly, there are tens (not tonnes) of works from 2020 and they have only a few citations each (hundreds if I look at the works from the year 2017, which is still not a lot, comparing to popular works on artificial neural networks).

Are graphical models still widely used in modern computer vision? Do they have another name or they are so well-known that people simply don't cite these works as classical ones like the first works on integrals, derivatives, and linear least squares?

If they are still widely used, could you, please, provide recent popular works on graphical models in computer vision (or explain how they are popular but don't have such works)? If no, could you, please explain your point of view?